# Trying to Stop a service and restart another service in VB

Tags: vb.net

Hey guys I'm trying to stop one service and then restart a different service.

Right now I have this code to restart a service

> Public Sub RestartService(ByVal myServiceName As String)
>
> ```
>     Dim DataSource As String = TextBox1.Text
>     Dim sStatus As String
>     Dim myController As ServiceController
>
>     myController = New ServiceController
>     myController.MachineName = DataSource
>     myController.ServiceName = myServiceName
>
>     TextBox2.Text += "Stopping service """ & myServiceName & """...." & vbNewLine
>
>     If myController.Status = ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped Then
>         TextBox2.Text += "Service """ & myServiceName & """ is already stopped" & vbNewLine
>     Else
>
>         Try
>             myController.Refresh()
>             sStatus = myController.Status.ToString
>             myController.Stop()
>             myController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
>             TextBox2.Text += "Service """ & myServiceName & """ stopped..." & vbNewLine
>
>             TextBox2.Text += "Starting service """ & myServiceName & """...." & vbNewLine
>             myController.Refresh()
>             sStatus = myController.Status.ToString
>             myController.Start()
>             myController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
>             TextBox2.Text += "Service """ & myServiceName & """ started..." & vbNewLine
>         Catch exp As Exception
>             TextBox2.Text += exp.Message
>         End Try
>     End If
>
>
>
> End Sub
> ```

And this one to Stop a service:

> Public Sub StopService(ByVal myServiceName As String)
>
> ```
>     Dim DataSource As String = TextBox1.Text
>     Dim sStatus As String
>     Dim myController As ServiceController
>
>     myController = New ServiceController
>     myController.MachineName = DataSource
>     myController.ServiceName = myServiceName
>
>     TextBox2.Text += "Stopping service """ & myServiceName & """...." & vbNewLine
>
>     If myController.Status = ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped Then
>         TextBox2.Text += "Service """ & myServiceName & """ is already stopped" & vbNewLine
>     Else
>
>         Try
>             myController.Refresh()
>             sStatus = myController.Status.ToString
>             myController.Stop()
>             myController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
>             TextBox2.Text += "Service """ & myServiceName & """ stopped..." & vbNewLine
>
>         Catch exp As Exception
>             TextBox2.Text += "Could not stop service """ & myServiceName & """" & vbNewLine
>         End Try
>     End If
>
>
>
> End Sub
> ```

But when I try to click this button, it only stops the first service and it doesn't restart the second service.

> Private Sub Button19_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles
> Button19.Click
>
> ```
>     If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to restart Spooler Service?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
>
>     StopService("LPDSVC")
>
>
>     RestartService("Spooler")
>
> End Sub
> ```

What am I missing inbetween stop and restartservice?

Comment: It is a simple copy-paste bug, RestartServer() does not do anything useful when the service is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the code is right and its working, I was testing it in the wrong way.
Its solved